# jQuery typewriter plugin that can be used with text input placeholders

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have looked all over for a plugin that can do the typewriter effect in a text input placeholder, but I haven't found any.

I have also tried to build one myself, but it's difficult.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can do that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPjPOW

Comment: Similar, but I need it to type in the placeholder

Comment: Yep, typed.js will work. http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/ 

Just use the attr: 'placeholder' option, I updated the codepen to reflect it working.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPjPOW

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer that [rch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5026094/rch) gave me.

Yep, [typed.js](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) will work. Just use the `attr: 'placeholder'` option. I updated the codepen to reflect it working: [See Codepen Snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRwMPq)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery PlaceholderTypewriter](https://github.com/mybsdc/jquery-placeholder-typewriter). It's built specifically for this purpose.

[image: Preview GIF]

For eg:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
```

And add script:

```
var placeholderText = [
    "Where would you like to go?",
    "Amsterdam?", 
    "Paris?", 
    "Berlin?", 
    "London?", 
    "New York?", 
    "San Francisco?"
  ];
```

$('#search').placeholderTypewriter({text: placeholderText});

For more advanced usage, see:

- [How To Use](https://github.com/mybsdc/jquery-placeholder-typewriter#how-to-use)
- [jQuery Placeholder typewriter](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Animated-Placeholders-placeholderTypewriter.html)